# How to stop "emacsclient -t -a '' --eval" output to stdout?

Tags: emacsclient, terminal-emacs

I am running emacsclient with the command:

```
emacsclient -t -a "" --eval "some-exp"
```

The `emacsclient -t -a ""` is a must.

The problem is, for example, if I run:

```
emacsclient -t -a "" --eval "nil"
```

when quitting emacsclient, the command line will have "nil" printed.

My question is, how to totally stop the printing of the returned value ? (in here, it's nil).

Comment: Would answer that prints output to `STDERR` Instead be acceptable?

Comment: @Melioratus yes, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your concern. `emacsclient`'s `--eval/-e` always eval one expression and print the result to stdout, if you don't care about the result, simply ignore it or redirect it to `/dev/null`. Anyway, it's easy to stop printing, you can use

```
(define-advice server-eval-and-print (:filter-args (args) no-print)
  (list (car args) nil))
```

to advice `server-eval-and-print` to just eval and bypass print. It should be easy to know how it works by taking a look at the function `server-eval-and-print` in source code.

If you don't have `define-advice`, which was added in Emacs 25.1, use this instead:

```
(defun server-eval-and-print@no-print (args)
  (list (car args) nil))

(advice-add 'server-eval-and-print :filter-args
            #'server-eval-and-print@no-print)
```

Comment: How did you trace down to 'server-eval-and-print' from the mere fact --eval "sexp" evaluates an sexp?

Comment: btw, redirecting stdout to /dev/null will make emacsclient -t -a "" fail to launch.

Comment: @FunkyBaby Here is how `server-eval-and-print` do the evaluation: `(eval (car (read-from-string expr)))`, so if you pass multiple sexp, it always the first one and ignore the rest.

Comment: @FunkyBaby I assumed you only want to redirect the output of `--eval/-e`. I don't understand why you need use `-t` and `--eval/-e` together. the `-t` makes no sense when `--eval/-e` exists, though It's should be OK. Of course, you can't do something like `emacsclient -t foo.txt > /dev/null` or `vi foo.txt > /dev/null`.

Comment: What if I just want to omit the "nil" to stdout, not anything else?

Comment: @CodyChan You can try to check the value in `server-eval-and-print`, if it's `nil`, don't print, otherwise, print the value.