# Preventing emacsclient eval from messing up my terminal

Tags: emacsclient, terminal-emacs, info, eval

I use emacs as info viewer from the terminal, but if the info page does not exist (or there is any other error) the terminal (regardless of Kitty or Konsole) becomes hardly usable, not properly reacting to input, especially not processing enter anymore, as well as not properly handling the terminal width:

[image]

Tried the following unsuccessfully:

- the advice from [How to stop "emacsclient -t -a '' --eval" output to stdout?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28989/how-to-stop-emacsclient-t-a-eval-output-to-stdout)
- `--suppress-output` from [How to suppress emacsclient --eval output](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64162/how-to-suppress-emacsclient-eval-output)
- redirecting to `/dev/null` prevents breaking my terminal but also the info display...

Currently I work around this by first checking whether an info page exists with `info "$@" -w | grep -v "manpages" | grep -q .`, but I would like a proper solution...

Edit: Somehow this happens due to the `--tty` flag, which also swallows the error message:

[image: comparison with and without --tty]

Comment: Does `stty sane` fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on my system, but I've also no idea how to test, as the `ls` output in your example seems fine, and `yay` isn't a program I have.  What's a more common command which reproduces the issue?  (Edit: oh, I see the weird `%` after the `ls` output now... well, I certainly don't see that, so I presume I'm not experiencing your issue.)

Comment: `stty sane` fixes it, yeeha!
It is also visible in that escape sequences are not properly handled anymore, so I see `^M` and `^C` in the terminal when typing RET and C-c, respectively.
Maybe related to doom and my configuration...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using zsh (Powerlevel10k) and Emacs (Spacemacs).

When I run `git commit`, it should open Emacs in terminal mode for me to enter the commit message. My `.gitconfig` is as follows:

```
[core]
    editor = emacsclient -c -a ''
```

Upon exiting Emacs, I'd see the same weird behavior in my terminal.

`stty sane` fixed the issue for me. Now I need to figure out how to run that automatically after leaving emacs.